# Spring loading set with Integer values

Tags: java, spring, set

I'm using Spring to load a Set containg integers:

```
<util:set id="ModifiableTags" set-class="java.util.HashSet">
        <value>44</value>
        <value>38</value>
        <value>111</value>
        <value>110</value>
        <value>40</value>
</util:set>
```

However, when I get the bean it always turns into a Set of String.

```
Set<Integer> tags = (HashSet<Integer>)clientAppContext.getBean("ModifiableTags");
for(Integer tag : tags) { // EXCEPTION as String can't be converted to Integer!
}
```

How do I force Spring to load the values as Integer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<util:set set-class="java.util.HashSet" value-type="java.lang.Integer">
    <!-- ... -->
</util:set>
```